# Agora cloud recording custom layout not working

Tags: cloud, recording, agora.io, conference, videocall

Agora is not capturing the video stream in custom layout when uid passed. It skip that stream in which uid is passed.

here is the sample layout  for three video stream I am using, it only capture two video stream in which uid is not present.

The uid I am passing is as per documentation in cloud recording which is 32 bit integer. The uid is manually generated not generated by Agora.

**layout for first 15 seconds**

```
"layoutConfig": [
                    {
                        "x_axis": 0.0,
                        "y_axis": 0.0,
                        "width": 1.0,
                        "height": 0.8,
                        "alpha": 1.0,
                        "render_mode": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "x_axis": 0.0,
                        "y_axis": 0.8,
                        "width": 0.5,
                        "height": 0.2,
                        "alpha": 1.0,
                        "render_mode": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "uid": "99142190",
                        "x_axis": 0.5,
                        "y_axis": 0.8,
                        "width": 0.5,
                        "height": 0.2,
                        "alpha": 1.0,
                        "render_mode": 1
                    }
                ]
```

**layout after 15 seconds**

```
"layoutConfig": [
            {
                "x_axis": 0.0,
                "y_axis": 0.0,
                "width": 1.0,
                "height": 0.8,
                "alpha": 1.0,
                "render_mode": 1
            },
            {
                "uid": "99142190",
                "x_axis": 0.0,
                "y_axis": 0.8,
                "width": 0.5,
                "height": 0.2,
                "alpha": 1.0,
                "render_mode": 1
            },
            {
                "x_axis": 0.5,
                "y_axis": 0.8,
                "width": 0.5,
                "height": 0.2,
                "alpha": 1.0,
                "render_mode": 1
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agora cloud recording with custom layout and custom generated uid's are not working.
Need to **use agora generated uid's** to record in custom layout in cloud recording.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using a string when generating the UID.
Although the API requires that a string be given, the UID itself must be a numeric type.